# Pandas Pivot Table on Switch From Dates Ascending to Descending Order

Tags: pandas, pivot, pivot-table

suppose I have a df that looks like this below:

I need to pivot the df at the exact row where the YYMMDD changes from ascending dates to a descending date - and then do that repeatedly until that pattern stops. So, here is an example df1:

```
        YYMMDD  HHMM  BestGuess(kWh)
0     20180101  100    20
1     20180101  200    70
0     20201231  2100   50
1     20201231  2200   90
2     20201231  2300   70
3     20210101  000    40    
4     20180101  100    5
5     20180101  200    7
6     20201231  2100   2
7     20201231  2200   3
8     20201231  2300   1
9     20210101  000    4
```

I need the new df (dfpivot) to look like this:

```
        YYMMDD  HHMM  BestGuess(kWh)_1  BestGuess(kWh)_2
0     20180101  100    20               5
1     20180101  200    70               7
2     20201231  2100   50               2
3     20201231  2200   90               3
4     20201231  2300   70               1
5     20210101  000    40               4
```

Comment: Following your edit, things are now clearer, but you still have duplicated column names ("BestGuess (kwh)").

Comment: yeah, here it is more clearly:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Initial dataframe
     YYMMDD  HHMM  bestguess
0  20180101   100         20
1  20190101   200         70
2  20200101  2100         50
3  20180101   100          2
4  20190101   200          4
5  20200101  2100         10
6  20170505    19         14
```

```py
# Create a list of index where the YYMMDD changes from ascending dates to a descending date
indices = [0]
for i in df.index:
    try:
        if df.iloc[i, 0] < df.iloc[i - 1, 0]:
            indices.append(i)
        else:
            continue
    except IndexError:
        continue

# Create a list of sub dataframes (splited from main dataframe)
dfs = []
for i in range(0, len(indices)):
    try:
        dfs.append(df[indices[i] : indices[i + 1]])
    except IndexError:
        dfs.append(df[indices[i] :])

# Merge sub dataframes
new_df = dfs[0]
for i, df in enumerate(dfs[1:]):
    new_df = pd.merge(
        right=new_df,
        left=df,
        how="outer",
        suffixes=(f"_{i}", f"_{i+1}"),
        on=["YYMMDD", "HHMM"],
    )

new_df = new_df.fillna(0)
```

```
# New dataframe
     YYMMDD  HHMM  bestguess  bestguess_0  bestguess_1
0  20170505    19       14.0          0.0          0.0
1  20180101   100        0.0          2.0         20.0
2  20190101   200        0.0          4.0         70.0
3  20200101  2100        0.0         10.0         50.0
```